# Validation in NodeJS express

Tags: node.js

code

if (req.body.phone === undefined || !req.body.phone || req.body.email === undefined || !req.body.email)

how apply validation on this in NodeJS

Comment: What do you mean by “validation”? Your question is unclear, I suggest you to rephrase it so others can understand it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
const phonenumber = function(phoneNo) {
  
  // Basic phone number regex
  const phoneNoRegex = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;

  // Returns true if phone number is valid
  // Else returns false
  return phoneNo.match(phoneNoRegex)
  
}
```

**Note: the regex can vary with country codes.**

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the different data that you want to validate and accordingly you can validate.

There is a NPM [Validator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/validator) package that provides a lot of validation properties for different types of data.

You can simply install it and do validation accordingly.